# Android universal image loader get picture

Tags: android, image

i'm using the library universal image loader to show pictures. It's working, i've my picture in every item in the listview. I have that :

```
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getContext()).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); 
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).build(); 
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri, imgView, options);
```

But i want to save this picture in a bitmap like 'Bitmap myImage', how can i do that ?

thx,

Comment: You question is not clear, You want image as bitmap too? Did you tried Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); ?

Comment: currently i'm just setting directlty the image in my listview. But i want to save it before in one of my object. (as bitmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri, imgView, options);
```

to

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri, imgView, options,new ImageLoadingListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1, FailReason arg2)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2)
    {
      // arg2 will give you the Bitmap you want
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1)
    {
    }
});
```

If the image is downloaded successfully from the provided `URL` then `onLoadingComplete` will be called and you will be able to get the image as a `Bitmap`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.You can get the image in bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
Util.CopyStream(is, os);
os.close();
bitmap = decodeFile(f);
```